# Should I check if array/collection value exists before trying to get it?

Tags: php

Should I check if a key exists and then get it or just get it (when I need to get it, not check if its set)?

What is more reliable? safer? faster?

Examples:

1) PHP redis (https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis)

```
if ($redis->exists('key'))
    echo $redis->get('key');
// VS
if ($value = $redis->get('key'))
    echo $value;
```

2) PHP phalcon cookies(http://docs.phalconphp.com/pt/latest/reference/cookies.html)

```
if ($this->cookies->has('remember-me'))
    echo $this->cookies->get('remember-me')->getValue()
// VS
if ($value = $this->cookies->get('remember-me')->getValue())
    echo $value;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Let's put it this way - what happens if you get a key that doesn't exist? As for speed - the less you have to do, the faster it is. Simple rule of our Universe that applies to everything, including computers.

Comment: The two methods you propose do not have the same behavior; if a key's value happens to be the empty string (a falsey value), the `if` condition will not be evaluated. Depending on how you are using the value, you may have to test `$value !== null` in the `if`.

Comment: If the key doesn't exists it will return false or null most of the time (depending on the library) and the echo statement will not be executed. and about the second comment... for this case lets assume that the values I'd like to extract are non-empty strings and if it's empty or null its fine if it doesn't echo it.

Comment: The condition should be `if (($value = $redis->get('key')) !== false) { ... }`; too bad if you stored `false` as a value :)

Comment: I'm guessing the second for Phalcon one will crash, because most likely the ->get will not return an object for a non-existing key, so the ->getValue will be called on a nil.
Also, the speed difference here is negligable. Don't optimise things that don't make a difference, it's not worth it.

Comment: Wrong guess, it does work. I always check.

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of this problem is:

**I don't like writing things like**

```
if ($value = $redis->get('key'))
    echo $value;
```

it makes code unclear.

Also, why is checking if variable exists so important? **Because it simplifies control flow.**

Let's consider that you're grabbing some data from service to render it on page. You can write low quality code with multiple `if`s, but you can also try something like this:

**offerServiceImpl.php**

```
class offerServiceImpl implements offerService {

    //... (some methods)

    /**
     * @param int $offerId
     * @return Offer
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     * @throws RuntimeException
     */
    public function getOffer($offerId)
    {
        if (!$offerId || !is_numeric($offerId)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Invalid offer id: " . $offerId);
        }

        $offer = $this->offerDao->get($offerId);

        if (!$offer) {
            //could be your own exception class
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not found offer " . $offerId);
        } else {
            return $offer;
        }
    }

}
```

**offersControler.php**

```
class offersController extends AbstractController{


    public function index($id){

        //... some code
        try{
            $offer = $this->offerService->getOffer($id);
        } catch (InvalidArgumentException $ex) {
            //log error, perform redirect to error 500
        } catch (RuntimeException $ex){
            //log another error, perform redirect to error 404
        } catch (Exception $ex){
            //log error, perform redirect to error 500
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Writing a high quality code is important. but sometimes it can interfere with the "need for speed". So I make some compromises (although my code is fairly awesome in terms of quality) . I need my code to be fast and efficient. one of the reasons i'm using phalcon.

Comment: I thought the same way... until I sat down in front of 1.5M lines of old bloated, Zend crappy code. That thing teaches a lesson. IMO there shouldn't be any compromises when it comes to code quality, it pays back. In fact you might thing that code I presented requires more work and more time to develop. That's true, but only at the beginning of a project. In time you start reusing things... and reusing well written things saves a lot of time.

Comment: I refered to the runtime rather than development time, but we all know that time is the most important thing in the world.